# SQLite - Problem with DateTime format when query any row comparing DateTime into WHERE clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

Let's say i'm having a database which includes a table like this:
`CREATE TABLE tbl_EX (_id TEXT, TIME TEXT);`
And then I insert a value like this:

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String time = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("_id", "SomeID");
contentValues.put("TIME", time);
database.insert("tbl_EX", null, contentValues);
```

After that, I try to query. Without `WHERE` clause:

```
database.query("tbl_EX", new String[]{"_id", "TIME"}, null, null, null, null, "TIME");
```

It retrieved me all records as expected, which are shown in 2 TextView like this:

```
_id = SomeID | Time = 2019-03-30 15:00:00
```

BUT, when I make query with this `WHERE` clause:

```
database.query("tbl_EX", new String[]{"_id", "TIME"}, "date(TIME) = ?", new String[]{"date('now')"}, null, null, "TIME");
```

No data found! I even try replacing the part `new String[]{"date('now')"}` to
 `new String[]{"date('2019-03-30')"}`or 
 `new String[]{"strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now')"}` or even 
`new String[]{"'2019-03-30'"}`, still no go.
So, did I store the DateTime data in the SQLite database in the right way? And querying it in the right way too??

Comment: You can try to set not equality, but `>` or `<` if you are sure you search right strings. Also you can try to print `date('2019-03-30')` or other sentences in any SQLite browser you know (see https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass

```
new String[]{"date('now')"}
```

as an argument, this is translated to this query:

```
select _id, TIME from tbl_EX where date(TIME) = 'date('now')'
```

Can you see the problem?
`date('now')` is treated as a string argument for the `WHERE` clause, so your query searches for literals `date('now')` in the column `TIME`.
What you should do instead is this:

```
database.query("tbl_EX", new String[]{"_id", "TIME"}, "date(TIME) = date(?)", new String[]{"now"}, null, null, "TIME");
```

This way the parameter `now` will be passed and your query will be:

```
select _id, TIME from tbl_EX where date(TIME) = date('now')
```

Similarly when you want to filter for a specific date like `2019-03-30` you must do:

```
database.query("tbl_EX", new String[]{"_id", "TIME"}, "date(TIME) = ?", new String[]{"2019-03-30"}, null, null, "TIME");
```

So you pass `2019-03-30` without the single quotes. 
Everything you include in the `selectionArgs` parameter is treated as a String literal and will be actually **surrounded by single quotes** in the statement that will be executed. 
You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).